# Width in d3 heatmap

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

This is my sample code. My intention is to generate a heatmap with rectangles like [image: this]

```js
var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          gridSize = Math.floor(width / 22),
          legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
          buckets = 9,
          colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
          days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
          times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];
          datasets = ["data.tsv", "data2.tsv"];

      var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
          .data(days)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

      var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

        var data= [
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 1,
  "value": 16
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 2,
  "value": 20
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 3,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 4,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 5,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 6,
  "value": 2
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 7,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 8,
  "value": 9
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 9,
  "value": 25
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 10,
  "value": 49
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 11,
  "value": 57
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 12,
  "value": 61
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 13,
  "value": 37
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 14,
  "value": 66
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 15,
  "value": 70
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 16,
  "value": 55
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 17,
  "value": 51
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 18,
  "value": 55
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 19,
  "value": 17
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 20,
  "value": 20
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 21,
  "value": 9
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 22,
  "value": 4
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 23,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 1,
  "hour": 24,
  "value": 12
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 1,
  "value": 6
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 2,
  "value": 2
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 3,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 4,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 5,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 6,
  "value": 2
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 7,
  "value": 4
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 8,
  "value": 11
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 9,
  "value": 28
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 10,
  "value": 49
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 11,
  "value": 51
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 12,
  "value": 47
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 13,
  "value": 38
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 14,
  "value": 65
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 15,
  "value": 60
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 16,
  "value": 50
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 17,
  "value": 65
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 18,
  "value": 50
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 19,
  "value": 22
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 20,
  "value": 11
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 21,
  "value": 12
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 22,
  "value": 9
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 23,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 2,
  "hour": 24,
  "value": 13
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 1,
  "value": 5
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 2,
  "value": 8
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 3,
  "value": 8
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 4,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 5,
  "value": 0
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 6,
  "value": 2
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 7,
  "value": 5
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 8,
  "value": 12
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 9,
  "value": 34
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 10,
  "value": 43
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 11,
  "value": 54
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 12,
  "value": 44
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 13,
  "value": 40
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 14,
  "value": 48
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 15,
  "value": 54
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 16,
  "value": 59
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 17,
  "value": 60
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 18,
  "value": 51
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 19,
  "value": 21
 },
 {
  "day": 3,
  "hour": 20,
  "value": 16
 }
]
          var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
              .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
              .range(colors);

          var cards = svg.selectAll(".hour")
              .data(data, function(d) {return d.day+':'+d.hour;});

          cards.append("title");

          cards.enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)
              .attr("class", "hour bordered")
              .attr("width", gridSize+10)
              .attr("height", gridSize)
              .style("fill", colors[0]);

          cards.transition().duration(1000)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

          cards.select("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });
          
          cards.exit().remove();

          var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });

          legend.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend");

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
            .attr("y", height)
            .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
            .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("class", "mono")
            .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
            .attr("y", height + gridSize);

          legend.exit().remove();
```

```css
rect.bordered {
        stroke: #E6E6E6;
        stroke-width:2px;   
      }

      text.mono {
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Consolas, courier;
        fill: #aaa;
      }

      text.axis-workweek {
        fill: #000;
      }

      text.axis-worktime {
        fill: #000;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="dataset-picker"></div>
```

I am using the code in published [here](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084). My intention is to increase the width. So I am adding a +10 to the grid size to my rects. But my heatmap still appears a collection of squares. My intention is to have a heatmap with rectangles rather than squares.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path, your grid widths have increased. You can check this if you right click on any of the tile and inspect element. But what is happening is that your grids are still overlapping at the same distance, therefore appearing as squares. You need to add the 10px to the x as well so that they do not overlap.

```
cards.enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * (gridSize+10); }) //10px added to the gridSize for the x displacement
              .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)
              .attr("class", "hour bordered")
              .attr("width", gridSize+10)
              .attr("height", gridSize)
              .style("fill", colors[0]);
```

Hope this helps.

A cautionary note for the future though, in the above code, the original gridSize is calculated based on the variable `width`. Since the rectangles are larger than the gridSize, your rectangles will most likely go out of your svg container and get cut. To fix this you will have to interchange the roles, i.e. set the gridSize and then calculate the width based on the `gridSize+10`. Let me know if you need help with this as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved my problem. But do you have any idea how to make it scrollable? If I scroll vertically the cells should move with the y-axis labels similarly, during horizontal scrolling the cells should move along with the xaxis labels.

Comment: Hi virupaksha. Glad I could help. The effect you are looking for is called `brush` or panning. Try searching for that and implementing it. Would recommend you to make another question if you have issues with that, as that is very different from this question title.

Comment: @Coola I came to this answer via google, but it does not seem to be working. here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjRpoG the boxes are still overlapping. Can you take a look at it please? thanks

Comment: @alt255 in your code you do not have the `gridSize+10` in brackets. This needs to be in brackets so that the entire value is multiplied by the hour value. So that line should be: `.attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * (gridSize+10); })`. Also note that your graph is going beyond your svg limits. So you may want to adjust your gridSize calculation in the beginning. Here is the corrected codepen with the correct axis labels as well https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZwjyz

Comment: thanks @Coola. I can not figure out why you are diving by 40 instead of 22 `gridSize = Math.floor(width / 40)` ??

Comment: @alt255, as I mentioned above it is to fit the graph to the svg size. If you do 22, the rectangles go out of the svg container and therefore the plot gets cut.

Comment: i know that. I am asking how did you come with `40` through trying different values?

Comment: @alt255 if you look at the code the variable width is calculated as `width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,` i.e. the `width = 930`. Since there are 24 rectangles representing 24 hours of the day you divide 930/24 = 38.75. I chose 40 just to be safe from all margins.